# Protractor/CucumberJS/Gup - e2e tests stop running when single test fails instead of continuing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing, cucumberjs, webdriverjs

When you're running your suite of e2e tests via a CI server like Bamboo; you expect to come back the next day or hour to see a report showing how many tests passed/failed.

In my case, my e2e tests stop running as soon as a single test fails so I come back the next morning to check the nightly build and do not have that nice report showing the stats on what passed/failed.

Checking the log file, I can see that there were some cucumber features that passed earlier on in the log prior to the failed feature; but again, a failing feature halts/stops the execution of any further tests in my situation.

The error would look something like:

```
AssertionError: expected 'Green' to equal 'Red'
[launcher] BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining
error   17:59:29    
error   17:59:29    C:\Users\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\PROJ\gulp\e2e-tests.js:27
error   17:59:29          throw err;
error   17:59:29          ^
error   17:59:29    Error: protractor exited with code 100
```

How can I force the test suite to continue running even if some features fails so that I can finally make it to that end report with the stats: passed/failed?

***Could it be a conflicting issue between how Protractor handles promises vs how chai/chai-as-promised does?***

```
Protractor v 4.0.1
Chai v 3.4.0
Chai-as-promise v ^5.1.0
Windows 10
cucumber@0.6.0 - **`I found this with npm list cucumber`**
Node v 4.4.7
Gulp
  CLI version 3.9.1
  Local version 3.9.1
```

Comment: I think we'd need to see a lot more of the actual step code for the steps that fail before anyone here can provide a useful answer.. 

That said, potentially you could be running into this protractor issue https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3491

Comment: I actually fixed this issue already by returning promises and completly ignoring callbacks, thanks for your brave attempt at answering the question

Comment: @pelican Did you fixed this? Same as your description here. I wanted my tests to continue on the next it block even if the present it block failed.